# Node.js 2016 - monitoring service

Tags: monitoring, node.js

we are looking for good monitoring service for Node.js in 2016.

New Relic is great, but it is also quite expensive. Does anyone know about good monitoring service which is cheap/free?

We especially want to monitor the (average) time of endpoints and/or methods.

PS : Appdynamics look good too, but it does not support Node 5+ now, the only option I found is to

Comment: What is considered cheap?

Comment: @Tom - always depends on our current needs and usability. If you know something, post it, we can always try it.

Comment: What features do you need? Is 100% command-line OK?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - we would like to have some web-based visual controller and what is important - we want the monitoring to be integreated into node.js - for example, you can require new relic module into your project as ordinary module and it is reporting it back to server without installing any agents and it also can scan the run-time on code-level

Comment: Please add all requirements to the body of your question, comments will be deleted, thanks! :-)